# What's the size of a 1px x 1px square?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graphics, draw

I'm coding a symmetry heavy program, and things aren't working as expected. One of the possible reasons is that I'm misinterpreting the measure units.

In a Flash and AS3 context, what's the size of a 1px x 1px square? Is it drawing just one pixel? Is a 1px x 1px square nothing more than a pixel? As in:

```
1px square: .

2px square: ..
            ..

3px square: ...
            ...
            ...
```

Are these examples correct? In other words, is a 1px x 1px square a dot and not a square?

Comment: Although you would have misinterpreted the actual size of 1 pixel. How would that possible effect your symmetry?

Comment: If you're trying for symmetry and accuracy, you might be better off making png images of what you want, so you know exactly what size they are and not rely on Flash's drawing class.  Line width, rounded edges and filters can change the absolute size of an object.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk Because I need to make calculations between several objects with inversed velocity vectors that need to bounce exactly at the same time from different positions: i need to calculate the exact center of the canvas, I need to calculate the exact center of the shapes, i need to calculate the positioning of the shapes on the canvas, ratios, relations, etc. If I'm 1 pixel off the whole system collapses. It loses symmetry.

Comment: @Gone3d I would still need to make the same calculations. This information about the measurement system will help me both draw shapes and accurately implement movement, positioning and collision dynamics.

Comment: Use images, that way you can calculate them accurately. If they're all in using the same scale and coordinate system, it should work.  You might have to check your math at some point if things are still not working the way you expect.

Comment: @Gone3d What's the difference? Both drawings and images use the same measurement system and unit. I still need to know this to position and move them correctly and to implement a successful symmetrical collision system. The question is analogue to "the actual size of a 1px x 1px image".

Comment: Actual size in what measurement system?

Comment: pixels can be any size if you want to measure them by inches or mm - the size of an image is dependent on two things - width and height in pixels and resolution in pixels/inch.  On a screen that size is dependent on the DPI - or dots per inch.  So from one screen to the next you get different actual physical sizes for a pixel.

Comment: @Gone3d That's not my doubt. My doubt is: a 1px x 1px square (or image) is the same as just one pixel? I put an example on the question post.

Comment: Ah - I think I know what you mean.  It's in relation to the moveTo, lineTo functions in flash.  That was what I was getting at above.  An image is exact and flash can be inexact on it's primitive shapes, especially if you add line width.  It allows for .5, 1.5, etc.  So that would cause things to be less precise.  If you use images/pngs you will have the exact size in pixels without wondering if something is more or less what it should be.

Comment: @Gone3d Haha I'm sorry If I'm not being clear enough. That's not my doubt either. It's simpler. Let's say I don't have line width, and I'm using only integers. Would a 1px x 1px square look like this: . ? Just one pixel?

Comment: @wvxvw I'm not interested in the physical size of pixels in different devices/screens. I'm interested in the specifics of the flash/as3 measurement system. In other words, do a 1px x 1px square looks like this: . ? Just one pixel? More examples in the main question post.

Comment: @wvxvw In other words, is a 1px x 1px square just a dot and not a square, in a flash - as3 context?

Comment: it's a square.  Flash allows for you to scale things down, so at some point, the square can be internally smaller than 1x1. Draw a square on the stage with a default outline, make its size to 10x10, then covert it to a bitmap and the it becomes 11x11.  These are the things to avoid.  Scale it down to 0.5x0.5  - it's still there and smaller than a pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a pixel is an object with an implied area and thusly differs from other measurement units for length such as meters, feet, etc. Therefore, 1px = 1x1px whereas 1m ≠ 1x1m.

*Edit: This applies when discussing pixels from a software point of view. It gets more complex when trying to convert between pixel "units" to real-world units since a pixel doesn't have specified dimensions, and doesn't even need to be square.*

Comment: My doubt has a flash - as3 - graphics context, not a devise size context. The first part was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)